# Pandas - replacing strings with a certain length in multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a (n,m) dimensional dataframe, with columns that are "dtype objects", that has entries of different length strings. The df looks like the following:

```
      col1    col2    col3    col4    ...   colm
    |---------------------------------------------    
row1| str1,1  str1,2  str1,3  str1,4  ...   str1,m
row2| str2,1  str2,2  str2,3  str2,4  ...   str2,m
.   | .       .       .       .       ...   .
.   | .       .       .       .       ...   . 
.   | .       .       .       .       ...   .
rown| strn,1  strn,2  strn,3  strn,4  ...   strn,m
```

I want to replace particular strings with NaN's on a condition that the length of the string has to be less than 10, but only for certain columns.

Here's my code:

```
column_list = ['col1','col3']
df.loc[:,column_list] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(x,np.NaN) if len(x) < 10 else x)
```

The code is running without error, but unfortunately not actually doing anything to my values in those columns. I believe my issue has to do with the following part:

```
x.str.replace(x,np.NaN)
```

I don't think "x" should be in the "replace" function.

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do with `mask` after you get string length by `str.len`

```
s=df.apply(lambda x : x.str.len())<10
df.loc[:,column_list]=df.loc[:,column_list].mask(s)
```

Comment: Perfect! To clarify, "s" returns boolean values. What does the ".mask(s)" do exactly?

Comment: @DudeWah more like a bool selection , when True unselected which is NaN , also https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html